# Map<Integer,CorefChain> graph=document.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class) has some errors

Tags: stanford-nlp

The statement in offical page of the Stanford CoreNLP "Map graph=document.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class) has some errors about type compatibility that is exactly incompatible types: "inference variable VALUE has incompatible bounds equality constraints: Map
    upper bounds: Map,Object
  where VALUE is a type-variable:
    VALUE extends Object declared in method get(Class>)" Any idea of this , parser version or type conversion?

Comment: Could you provide some sample code that causes this error?

Comment: And what official page is this? If I look on http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html, I see: `Map<Integer, CorefChain> graph = …`, which is the correct typing….